# Diffeomorphic - Unable to use some hair

Tags: add-on, hair

I’ve been trying to use the “Side Swept ROse Hair” for G8 into Blender but when I try to make hair, it just crashes (definitely a RAM issue).

I’m not even able to separate the hair from the skull since there is no skull parts in the mesh. There is nothing I can do with it and it keeps crashing, what should I do?

‌[Image of model with hair (mild nudity)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U35RB.png)

Hair mesh:
[image: Hair]

Also, selecting strands by size didn’t help at all:

[image]

**EDIT:**
I've tried simplifying and decimating the mesh down to 10k but it didn't do much. From what I could get on the Diffeomorphic bitbucket, it seems to be an issue with UVs being both horizontal and vertical... And the addon doesn't have a way to deal with it. Also, even after separating horizontal and vertical UVs into multiple meshes and trying again, the tool requires way too much RAM and just crashes, this have been reported on the bitbucket as well.

Comment: Hi welcome to the site! I'm sorry I'm not sure I understand what "make hair" refers to, are you using an addon? What exactly are the steps that lead to blender crashing?

Comment: Hi, it's indeed an addon called "Diffeomorphic". The idea is that it imports models from Daz Studio to Blender and there are some tools used to simplify the process. One of them is "Make Hair" which converts the hair mesh to particle hair, but for some reason, this mesh creates issues on top of issues.